# How to get length of data object in angular 6

Tags: angular6

I have few data object and I wanna get length of the object before looping. To achieve this I am doing *latest_posts.length* but It's showing nothing.

post.ts

```
latest_posts:any;
getadPosts() {
    return this.http.get('http://example.com').subscribe( result=>
        this.latest_posts = result
        );
    }

ngOnInit() {      
    this.getadPosts();
  }
```

post.html

```
{{latest_posts.length}}
```

Comment: If the result you get back is an array, that should work. What's the return value?

Comment: I think returned value is  not an array

Comment: Can you please tell me How can convert the returned value into an array?

Comment: We cannot possibly say what the return value is. We don't have access to the server you're getting it from

Comment: How how can we check value type by the code?

Comment: when I am trying to say like console.log(this.latest_posts) then it returns as [object Object]

Comment: try console.log(JSON.stringify(this.latest_posts)) to see what is inside the [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

When a want to get the length of a obj I do this:

```
const length = Object.keys(myObj).length;
```